# Express MongoDB variable is not defined

Tags: express, mern

I have the following Schema for a User:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Schema
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    default: ""
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

For some annoying reason, I am getting `[eslint] User is not defined` error. What's wrong here?

I am using MERN stack webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should define User object first and then export it like as bellow

```
var User = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding:

```
/*globals User:true*/
```

at the top of the file. This dealt with Eslint solving `no-undef` and then `no-native-reassign` error.